# How can I group arrays in an array in PHP and encode to JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, grouping, encode

I have 2 tables in MySql

**Section**

```
section_id       name
=====================
1              Section1
2              Section2
```

**Category**

```
    category_id        section_id     name
    =========================================
    1                  1           Category1
    2                  1           Category2
    3                  2           Category3
    4                  2           Category3
```

This is what I have now:

```
$sections = mysql_query($sql_section) or die("Could not execute query.");
$categories = mysql_query($sql_category) or die("Count not execute query");

$result = array('sectionlist' => array());
    for ($i=0; $i < mysql_num_rows($sections); $i++ ){
        for ($j=0; $j < mysql_num_rows($categories); $j++){
            if (mysql_result($sections,$i,"section_id") == mysql_result($categories,$j,"section_id")){
                $result['sectionlist'][] = array('sectionName' => mysql_result($sections,$i,"name"), 'categorylist' => array(array('category' => mysql_result($categories,$j,"name"))));
            }
        }
    }
echo json_encode($result);
```

The result has came out is like this:

```
  {sectionlist:[
    {sectionName: "Section1", categoryList: [{categoryName: "category1"}]},
    {sectionName: "Section1", categoryList: [{categoryName: "category2"}]},
    {sectionName: "Section2", categoryList: [{categoryName: "category3"}]},
    {sectionName: "Section2", categoryList: [{categoryName: "category4"}]},
  ]}
```

This wasn't the expected result from me, I would like to have an object that look like this:

```
{sectionlist:[
    {sectionName: "Section1", categoryList: [{categoryName: "category1"}, {categoryName: "category2"}]},
    {sectionName: "Section2", categoryList: [{categoryName: "category3"}, {categoryName: "category4"}]}
]}
```

Therefore, how can I group the section 1 with section 1 and section with section 2?

Comment: Please post the query(s) you are executing. Also, avoid using the dated mysql_* functions. Using them for new code is highly
[discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query).
More modern alternatives are available and better maintained.
Consider learning about
[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
instead and use either
[PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
When used strictly they avoid the tedious and manual escaping part,
thus become heaps easier and as by-product safer to use.
See [a PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) for starting.

Comment: Thanks Greg. That's really important to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you want to create the array of categories first.

```
for ($i=0; $i < mysql_num_rows($sections); $i++ ){
    $categorylist = array();
    for ($j=0; $j < mysql_num_rows($categories); $j++){
        if (mysql_result($sections,$i,"section_id") == mysql_result($categories,$j,"section_id")){
            $categorylist[] = array('category' => mysql_result($categories,$j,"name");
        }
    }
    $result['sectionlist'][] = array('sectionName' => mysql_result($sections,$i,"name"), 'categorylist' => $categorylist));
}
```

As a sidenote, [PHP encourages use of the other database extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Answer (score 1):

@Greg's comment is really important to take note of above. Also, I would recommend re-writing your query as a single query with a join in order to retrieve just the data you want. I'm not 100% sure exactly what you'll need, but it will probably be something like this:

```
SELECT section.section_id, category.name, section.name FROM category 
  LEFT JOIN section ON section.section_id = category.section_id;
```

That will return an array of category names keyed to the section_id and section name that they're associated with (you can also select the category_id if you'd like).