# How to group Objects in an Array using PHP PDO and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, logic

I have this category table

```
Category
============
id    name    ref_id
1     cat1    0
2     cat2    0
3     subCat1 1
4     subCat2 1
5     subCat3 2
6     subCat4 2
```

I would like to have a result that look like this:

```
{items: [
    {catId: 1, subCat:[{name: subCat1}, {name:subCat2}]},
    {catId: 2, subCat:[{name: subCat2}, {name:subCat4}]}
]}
```

I've tried to approach this by:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=UTF-8', '', '');

$categories = $db -> query('SELECT * FROM category');

$results = array('items' => array());

foreach($categories as $row) {
    $subCategories = array();
    $results['items'][] = array('id' => $row['video_id'], 'subCat' => $subCategories);
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

I have no clue of what to do with subCategories in this case. Or Anything I do to fix the query of $categories? Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I group arrays in an array in PHP and encode to JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997109/how-can-i-group-arrays-in-an-array-in-php-and-encode-to-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the root categories, you need the add `where ref_id=0` to your query. And then in your `foreach` loop, you need to query again to get the current row's sub-categories (using `"where ref_id=".$row['id']` in the second query). You compile the `$subCategories` array using another `foreach` loop. O, and I replaced `'id' => $row['video_id']` from your code, to `'catId' => $row['id']` to get the result you require.

As follows:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', '', '');

$categories = $db->query('SELECT * FROM category where ref_id=0');

$results = array('items' => array());

foreach($categories as $row) {
  $subCategories = array();

  $sCategories = $db->query('SELECT * FROM category where ref_id='.$row['id']);
  foreach($sCategories as $subCat){
    $subCategories[] = array('name'=>$subCat['name']);
  }

  $results['items'][] = array('catId' => $row['id'], 'subCat' => $subCategories);
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

I have recreated your database on my side, and when I run this, I get

```
{"items":[
   {"catId":"1","subCat":[{"name":"subcat1"},{"name":"subcat2"}]},
   {"catId":"2","subCat":[{"name":"subcat3"},{"name":"subcat4"}]}
]}
```